# Why is my UILabel within a custom UITableViewCell not returning the proper height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` that contains a custom subclass of `UILabel` called `descriptionLabel` within it. I have a variable called `nativeHeight` that is supposed to be the height of the cell depending on the length of the text in the label. The cells for rows 2+ are set at a height of 50, unless they are selected, at which point they expand to the full height where the `UILabel` is visible. However, it's not returning the proper value to enable this. I'm defining it as follows (where 116 is the fixed height of all other content not including the UILabel):

```
var nativeHeight : CGFloat {
    return self.descriptionLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height + 116
}
```

The variable is called in the cell code:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if selected {
        self.cellHeightConstraint.constant = self.nativeHeight
    } else if !selected {
        self.cellHeightConstraint.constant = 50
    }
}
```

It is also called in the Table View code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        return 136
    case 1:
        return 50
    default:
        if selectedRow != nil && indexPath == selectedRow {

            tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! DynamicTableViewCell
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell.nativeHeight

        } else {
            return 50
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you change constraints you want to be calling `layoutIfNeeded()` for the changes to apply. And you don't need to implement heightForRowAt` if the constraints have be set up to calculate the cell height and you have automatic dimensioning enabled (this is default).

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about not using heightForRowAt. I still need it for rows 0 and 1, which are different types, and all code is working as is except for the incorrect calculation of the label. Where is layoutIfNeeded() supposed to be called that it isn't?

Comment: Because the tableView will automatically do the height calculation if you have your constraints set relative to the contentView. Also you need to call layoutIfNeed where you change your constraint. And if it changes the cell size then you need to update your table with `beingUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Answer (score 0):

Rakesha is correct you don't need heightForRowAtIndexPath. If you set it up correctly everything is calculated for you.

Set up the constraints on the first two cells correctly so you don't need to hardcode 136 and 50.

In regard to your third cell I would perhaps look into setting a height constraint on your description label, of 50. When you want your cell expanded you can just deactivate the height constraint and update the cells layout.

You will need to store the state (expanded, or not) of your cells somewhere so that when you scroll up and down you can enable/disable the height constraint correctly.

Comment: When I get rid of heightForRowAtIndexPath the expanded cell overlaps the cells below it - the cells further down the table view do NOT shift down to accommodate the expanded cell. Like I said, all of my code is working, except that I'm not getting the correct return on the value. It IS varying depending on content, but not by the correct amount. Is there really no way to get that variable to return the actual value after the cell has been laid out?

Comment: look at Rakesha last comment. did you update your table view after the cell is selected? there will be a way to calculate the height the label should be to fit the contents but thats the hard way to do it

Comment: Yes, I did update the table after selecting, and the cell after changing the height constraint. However, I'm still getting the issue of the selected (expanded) cell overlapping the other cells.